# How can I make "50% duty pwm signal" + "flicker signal" circuit?

Tags: pwm, 555

I'm new to electrical engineering.
I want to make 50% duty pwm signal(adjustable frequency) + flicker signal as following picture.
[image]

I think 50% duty pwm signal can be made using 555 timer like this
[image]

but I have no idea that how I can integrate this pwm signal into flicker signal with adjustable period.

Can I make it using additional 555 timer or something? I need your help.

Comment: Is *flicker* some kind of random delay between random length bursts of 50% PWM?

Comment: Since there is two timing sequences, two timer should be used. 2x 555 or 556.

Comment: "flicker signal" afaik is not a standardized term. What exactly do you mean by "flicker signal"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know exact term. For example, the signal I meant is the 50% PWM on for 3 seconds and the signal off for 1 second repeat.

Comment: not random, fixed time (like 3s, 1s)

Comment: As for many such applications, a small microcontroller such as a PIC offers a lot more versatility, as well as reduced parts count and cost. The 555 can handle higher supply voltage and higher output current, if those are important.

Comment: @JaehoLee You also need to specify the frequency for the 50% square wave. Or, if this is really a PWM where you supply a voltage or current signal used to adjust the duty cycle, what that control signal also looks like. But at least, for now, we know that the total period is 4 seconds and that for 75% of that period there is to be a PWM and for 25%, either a LO or a HI (also not specified so far.) Details and an example illustration might help if words fail you.